# Retrieve all localities and sub localities from given city google places API

Tags: google-places-api, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I am looking for a web service or a Google place API kind of plugin to retrive localities,sub-localities and areas of the given city name.

have been trying my hands with google and geonames but can't able to get through it.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=hyderabad&types=(locality)&language=en_US&key=My_KEY


https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?/?address=hyderabad&key=My_KEY
```

have tried these two ways. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

A city is defined as

> locality indicates an incorporated city or town political entity.

and a sublocality as:

> sublocality indicates a first-order civil entity below a locality.  For some locations may receive one of the additional types: sublocality_level_1 to sublocality_level_5.

in [address component types in geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types).  Also should refer the list of  [supported types to use](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) with the types request parameter and those returned by the Google APIs.

The idea is to start with a designated sublocality_level_1 in your city, retrieve sublocality_level_2s, store them to DB.  Repeat, but only this time with sublocality_level_2 to get the sublocality_level_3.  The key is to store geometry and addressName (longname, shortname etc) in DB, so that you can run them again to get adequate, if not all information, thus simulating a zooming behavior.  Finally use autocomplete APIs to retrieve a (sub)locality that don't make it to your store, but one you know should have been retrieved.

Substituting the level_1 sublocality, locality and level_1 admin areas in [geocoding request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingRequests) json:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=[sublocality.1],+[locality],+[admin_area_level.1]&key=API_KEY

Verify that the sublocality.1 ends up in the right place.

```
<address_component>
  <long_name>sublocality.1</long_name>
  <short_name>sublocality.1</short_name>
  <type>sublocality_level_1</type>
  <type>sublocality</type>
  <type>political</type>
</address_component>
<..></..>
<..></..>
<geometry>
  <location>
    <lat>nn.nnnnnnnnn</lat>
    <lng>nn.nnnnnnnnn</lng>
  </location>
```

Use [Radar search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#RadarSearchRequests) with query parameters location=&radius=10000&types=(regions)

Refering to [supported types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)

> The (regions) type collection instructs the Places service to return any result matching the following types:

Next is extract all the place_id, use the [place details API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults) that takes place_id as a query parameter and requires a api_key.

The [place details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults) response should have all sublocality_level_2s for chosen sublocality_level_1.  Store them to DB omitting duplicates by name.  At the end of this, you have one location for locality (city), chosen sublocality_level_1 and number of sublocality_level_2 Location entities persisted.

This should do for sublocality_level_2.  Since they occupy considerable area, missing them ideally may not happen, I believe.  Should you miss, use [Autocomplete APIs](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) if you know the starting characters or [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding) if you know the exact geometry of the missing level_2.

The above steps, repeat for sublocality_level_3 under a given level_2 of known name.

For every [geometry](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) use [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding) to get a level_3, which if not present in the store, running against the [Place details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults), retrieve sublocality_level_2 again and store.  This is needed as some level_3 directly are associated to level_1s.  This step is analogous to zooming carefully on the map to find a locality.

Use the JSON

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=&types=(regions)&location=latitude,longitude&radius=1000&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Note the () around regions.  That gives you the locality and others.  [Refer to https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete)

The whole process can be repeated with the sub_locality_type_1 adjacently co-located to the previously used one.  Use [nearby search (place search)](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) for this.  Query parameters for location should be the geometries of the southwest and northeast bounds of the above level_1 (sub) locality.  Note to use radius=1.  The JSON URI used is:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters